# Accessing elements of a User Control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a UserControl as follows:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MySample.MyControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MySample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Canvas>

    <Ellipse Width="150" Height="150"/>

    <TextBlock>Sample</TextBlock>

</Canvas>
```

Now, from my main page I would want to change the Text appearing in my User Control from "Sample" to Hello World. So, I did this in my mainpage.xaml

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="MyControl" Margin="100,50 0,0"></local:MyControl>
```

And in the mainpage.xaml.cpp when I try to reference MyControl, it seems unrecognized:

```
MainPage::MainPage(){MyControl->Text = "Hello World";}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Detailing out @Steven You's answer, in your UserControl define a `DependencyProperty`.
Defining a `DependencyProperty` allows change notifications to trigger updates to your controls.

In the code-behind of your UserControl you can add the dependency property.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string TextBlockText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextBlockTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBlockTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBlockTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextBlockText", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));


    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

This exposes a public `DependencyProperty` which you can bind to in your UserControl's XAML.

```
<UserControl>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextBlockText}" />
</UserControl>
```

Now you need a way to set that property from your Window control.  I'll detail three ways in which you can do this:

1.) Since the `TextBlockText` property is exposed on the UserControl we can set it directly in the XAML like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
  <local:MyUserControl TextBlockText="Text that you want to set.">
  </local:MyUserControl>
</Window>
```

2.) If we give the UserControl a name we can change the property within the Window code-behind:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
  <local:MyUserControl Name="CoolUserControl">
  </local:MyUserControl>
</Window>
```

-

```
CoolUserControl.TextBlockText = "Text that you want to set.";
```

3.) Or lastly you can create another `DependencyProperty` within your `Window`'s code-behind and bind it to the `UserControl`'s dependency property.  This way whenever you update the property the value within your `Window` code the `UserControl` dependency property will change too.  This is the preferable choice as @Steven You said before, since your code behind does not need to know about any controls.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public string UserControlText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UserControlTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserControlTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserControlTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("UserControlText", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        UserControlText = "Text that you want to set.";
    }
}
```

And to bind to our new `DependencyProperty` in the Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
    <local:MyUserControl TextBlockText="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=UserControlText}"></local:MyUserControl>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In program view, the best way to do this is using data binding rather than set the value in code behind. 
To solve this problem, the simplest way is to register a dependency property of the UserControl bind this value to the TextBlock and then set the value in MainPage.

Comment: can you give a small example on how to do it ?

Comment: Read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224230/Exploring-the-use-of-Dependency-Properties-in-User

Comment: Have a look at this databinding [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5)