# How to get all Properties of inside of usercontrol`s TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a `UserControl` in c# wpf. I want to get all properties of TextBox (txtCode) Property Box

[image]

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="315.358" Width="758">
    <Grid >
        <TextBox x:Name="txtCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="134,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00001" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="588" FontSize="30"/>
        <Label Content="Code" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="97" FontSize="30"/>
        <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,186,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="247" Height="48" FontSize="30"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In Windows form something Like below Image

[image]

c# Code

```js
 public TextBox txtCodeProperties
        {
            get { return txtCode; }
            set { txtCode = value; }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of a User Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986698/accessing-elements-of-a-user-control)

Comment: just press `F4` or `Alt+Enter` at the **focused control**, if you want to see "Properties of Control".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose the whole TextBox and all of it's properties, you should look into [x:FieldModifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905(v=vs.110).aspx). If you only need to expose some of the properties, you could expose them as DependencyProperties, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986698/accessing-elements-of-a-user-control).

How to use the FieldModifier:

In your `UserControl1`, add the `x:FieldModifier="public"` attribute to your TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCode" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="97" Margin="134,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00001" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="588" FontSize="30"/>
```

Then, whenever you use `UserControl1`, you now have public access to the textbox.

Example usage (xaml):

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="myUserControl1" />
```

Code-behind:

```
myUserControl1.txtCode.Text = "Hello, World!";
```

Comment: Pls give me an example for x:FieldModifier

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example of x:FieldModifier="public"

Comment: Then you should edit your question to clarify what exactly you want. The answer I gave gets you access to "all properties of TextBox", as you asked for.  I also included a link for what you can do if you only need some properties.

Comment: I edited my Question and also attached an example of windows form but it is not working in wpf  if do you have any idea pls share with me